# Capturing Async events

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous

Im struggling with a problem and need some options for possible solutions.

I have three layers - ClientApp, ServiceLayer and Domain Layer

The service layer and the domain layer implements a Publisher and Subscriber events pattern so that different areas of the domain can be notified when things happen.

The clientApp calls the domian to create a new order. On creation of the order the publisher raises an event to notify another are of the domain to do something. I am hooking into this event in the Service layer via a subscriber and the correct event is recieved.

I want the event to be bubbled up to the clientApp, but am struggling to get this to work. I think its because the events is trigger Asynchronously and are therefore not in the same thread. I have implemented a publish and subscriber between the clientApp and service layer, but again this failed.

ClientApp(create a new order)>ServiceLayer(recieves)>Domain(created order raises event)
ServiceLayer(recieves event)> ?????

Any help or guidance appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that ClientApp calls directly into the domain to create an order, shouldn't that the job of the ServiceLayer? To provide a facade over the domain? Aside from issues with design, you can't expect anyone to help with your technical problem without showing any code.

Comment: "I have implemented a publish and subscriber between the clientApp and service layer, but again this failed". Post the code for this. We have no idea what you have written.

Comment: I cannot provide any code that will easily explain - I after theoretical answer/potential solutions. Ithought I explained it simply - and order is submitted to the domain through my protection service layer the order is created and event is raised to tell someting in the servicelayer it was created - the client app needs to subscribe to this listener in the service layer, but how?

Comment: Solved it myself using RX. very tidy and neat solution